# Tensorflow installation on mac 10.11.6

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow in my mac 10.11.6
Nothing is working out yet.

I have tried python 2.7, 3.6 & 3.7.3 with tensorflow 1.13.1
nothing seemed to be working. I have tried many online installation tutorials too.

Can anyone tell me, how it can be fixed?

Comment: What's the error? How do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: tensorflow not found,

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'